# How to make a AVAudioPlayer start immediately playing after another has finished?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I have created two `AVAudioPlayer` instances:

```
introPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: introURL)
introPlayer?.numberOfLoops = 0
introPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
introPlayer?.delegate = self

loopPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: loopURL)
loopPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
loopPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
```

The delegate:

```
extension ViewController: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if player == introPlayer {
            _ = loopPlayer?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

And the simple launch function:

```
_ = introPlayer?.play()
```

My goal is to get the loopPlayer to start immediately after the introPlayer has finished, but I always end up with a slight delay, like half a second. I double-checked that this delay doesn't come from the tracks.

How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: To queue different sounds use an AVQueuePlayer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer

Comment: Could you either answer your own question or delete it, please?